# How to get database columns from more than one table in sql server and then group by table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario in which I want to fetch database table columns from two tables and then I want to group by table name,

e.g.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE table_name='lead' 
UNION ALL
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE table_name='CustomQuestion'  
GROUP BY
```

[image]

Comment: What is "group by table name" means? are you expecting group by table name and get column names in comma separated as single column?

Comment: the answer below working fine , but now i want to display table only once at top

Answer (score 3):

Why group, you have no aggregate? I think you mean ORDER BY

```
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
where TABLE_NAME in ('CustomQuestion','lead')
order by TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: its working fine, but i want to that table name should only be display one time at top i have added an image see question

Comment: @user3197214 That's not how SQL works. SQL server is not the same as Excel.

Comment: It's how SQL works if you write the query to do it.  I'm not advocating using SQL this way, but to claim the tool can't do what's asked is simply not true.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments, what you're asking for (table name to appear only once) is really more reporting functionality than query functionality; which is to say there's probably better ways to do it than wedge it into SQL.

But that doesn't mean you *can't* wedge it into SQL, so here you go:

```
select case when row_number() over(partition by table_name 
                                       order by column_name) = 1
            then TABLE_NAME
            else ''
       end as TABLE_NAME
     , COLUMN_NAME
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
 where TABLE_NAME in ('CustomQuestion','lead')
 order by TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: (Full disclosure - I'm not where I can test this.  If it fails for some reason, pushing the `row_number()` into a subquery should resolve any problem.  But I think it should work as written.)